# Macro for replacing matching tokens in a parameter?

Tags: automation, token-lists

I would like to have a macro, call it `\magicreplace` which gets some arbitrary parameter (= sequence of tokens)  and replaces every occurrence of some token (say, `a` or `x` or `,`) with some fixed sequence of tokens (say `hello`, or `\text{hello}`).

So, `\magicreplace{a}{abc{abc}}` expands to `hellobc{abc}`.

Is there something available in some package for doing that? If not, how would I go about implementing this thing?

Notes:

- Can be LaTeX rather than plain TeX
- pdftex and/or xetex please

Comment: since you use `\rm` I'm assuming you need this for plain tex not latex? Also do you need it for pdftex or would luatex or xetex solutions be OK?

Comment: if you are replacing a by hello what do you want   `abc{abc}` to produce? (`hellobc{abc}` is perhaps easier than `{hellbc{hellobc}`)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: See edits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is already available out of the box in `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\magicreplace}{mmm}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_einpoklum_magicreplace_tl { #3 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_einpoklum_magicreplace_tl { #1 } { #2 }
  \tl_use:N \l_einpoklum_magicreplace_tl
 }
\tl_new:N \l_einpoklum_magicreplace_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\magicreplace{a}{hello}{abc{abc}}

\magicreplace{a}{hello}{a b c{a b c}a}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different version where the replacement string is fixed (but changeable).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\magicreplace}{mm}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_einpoklum_magicreplace_tl { #2 }
  \tl_replace_all:NnV \l_einpoklum_magicreplace_tl { #1 } \l_einpoklum_magicreplace_rep_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_einpoklum_magicreplace_tl
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\setreplacement}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_einpoklum_magicreplace_rep_tl { #1 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l_einpoklum_magicreplace_tl
\tl_new:N \l_einpoklum_magicreplace_rep_tl
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_replace_all:Nnn { NnV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\setreplacement{hello}

\magicreplace{a}{hello}{abc{abc}}

\setreplacement{world}
\magicreplace{a}{a b c{a b c}a}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: where's the fun in stealing from boxes?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That Bruno does the work.

Comment: I suspected there was something like this deep under the hood.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to take more care over white space but a simple version is

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\zz#1#2#3{\def\zzz##1#1{##1#2\zzz}{\zzz#3\zzzz#1\relax}}
\def\zzzz#1\relax{}
\begin{document}

\zz{a}{hello}{abc{abc}abc}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What would the issue with whitespace be?

Comment: @einpoklume actually with that form space is probably Ok but if the list of tokens before the `a` is just a brace group, th ebraces would be dropped