# Replacing the star as in enumitem

Tags: macros

Enumitem provides a nice syntax `\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*]`, where `*` is replaced by the appropriate counter. I want to understand how this works (or, rather, how I can do something similar). I played around with the solution from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/377631/27717) and now have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newtoks\S
\let\ea\expandafter
\newcommand{\FormatCounter}[2]{%
    \def\replaceStar##1{%
        \def\@replaceStar####1*{####1{#1}}%
        \ea\S\ea{\@replaceStar##1\Ignore*\relax}%
    }%
    \def\Ignore##1\relax{}%
    \replaceStar{#2}%
    \showthe\S%
    \the\S%
}

\begin{document}
    \textit{asdf \FormatCounter{page}{(\alph*)} asdf}
    \textit{asdf \FormatCounter{page}{\textup{(\alph*)}} asdf}
\end{document}
```

The first replacement works, the second does not, because the replacement does not reach the star inside the group. How can I solve this?

Apparently, using

```
\ea\replaceStar\ea{\detokenize{#2}}%
```

runs without error and does the correct replacement, but then I have no idea how to undo the `\detokenize`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Rather than replacing `*` just make it locally be the right  counter.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\FormatCounter}[2]{{%
    \ExpandArgs{cc}\let{c@*}{c@#1}%
    #2%
}}

\begin{document}
    \textit{asdf \FormatCounter{page}{(\alph*)} asdf}
    \textit{asdf \FormatCounter{page}{\textup{(\alph*)}} asdf}
\end{document}
```